# parameters passing by ref in C#

Tags: c#, methods, ref

I'm new to programming and right now I'm doing some exercises, however, I couldn't complete one task (or I didn't understand), I'm stuck at number (3), can you help me ?
Here's exercise and my code:

(1)Should have a separate method for conversion

(2)Should have a separate method called ConvertSecondsToHoursMinutesSeconds

(3)Should have one int parameter passed by value and three int parameters
passed by ref

(4)Should correctly convert seconds to hours, minutes and seconds

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        conversion();
    }
    private void ConvertSecondsToHoursMinutesSecondsMethod(long totalSeconds) 
    {
        long hours, mins, secs, v;

        hours = totalSeconds / 3600;
        v = totalSeconds % 3600;
        mins = v / 60;
        secs = v % 60;
    }
    private void conversion(ref long hours, ref long secs, ref long mins)

    {
        long seconds = Convert.ToInt64(userInputLabel.Text);
        ConvertSecondsToHoursMinutesSecondsMethod(seconds);

        outputLabel.Content = $"{hours} {mins} {secs}";


    }
}
```

Comment: I also feel there something missing, like a problem presentation or context explanation. Is this the full content of assignment?

Comment: Yes, this is the full content of assignment

Comment: Due to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY and https://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time I think it'd be a good idea to encourage best practice here and use the `DateTime` library, and/or other platform classes for time processing, and not manual translation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

Also have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref for the correct way to use ref

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Conversion();
}
private void ConvertSecondsToHoursMinutesSecondsMethod(int totalSeconds, ref long hours, ref long secs, ref long min)
{
    long v;
    hours = totalSeconds / 3600;
    v = totalSeconds % 3600;
    min = v / 60;
    secs = v % 60;
}
private void Conversion()
{
    long hours = 0;
    long secs = 0;
    long mins = 0;
    int seconds = Convert.ToInt32(userInputLabel.Text);

    ConvertSecondsToHoursMinutesSecondsMethod(seconds, ref hours, ref mins, ref secs);

    outputLabel.Content = $"{hours} {mins} {secs}";
}
```

Comment: Whats the reason you changed `totalSeconds/seconds` from `long/Int64` to `int/Int32`?

Comment: As per OP's question. (3) Should have one int parameter passed by value

Comment: Well it also says `and three *int* parameters passed by ref` but you kept the long there

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the ref parameters received to the other method you are calling for them to receive correct values. Local variables usually fail to exist once a method returns.

```
private void ConvertSecondsToHoursMinutesSecondsMethod(long totalSeconds, ref long secs, ref long mins) 
{
    hours = totalSeconds / 3600;
    long v = totalSeconds % 3600;
    mins = v / 60;
    secs = v % 60;
}

private void conversion()
{
    long hours, secs, mins;
    long seconds = Convert.ToInt64(userInputLabel.Text);
    ConvertSecondsToHoursMinutesSecondsMethod(seconds, ref hours, ref secs, ref mins);

    outputLabel.Content = $"{hours} {mins} {secs}";
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I can see now